# Keycloak login page: Redirect to another client

Tags: keycloak

I have 2 clients within same realm in Keycloak,let's say: localhost:9090/first/ and localhost:9090/second/. What i want is - when user types: localhost:9090/first/  and  log in, Keycloak should redirect him/her to localhost:9090/second/ . But Keycloak server throws: "invalid url" when i save first client's "redirect uri" as: localhost:9090/second/.  Is it possible to redirect to another client?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @JoelB Hi! No :( I ended up using one client.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this url in valid url section of keycloak